# popup div box in jquery to edit given item?

Tags: jquery

So I have a bunch of LI elements initially with span text inside of "unrated". I'm trying to figure out how I would be able to press a button, get a popup div where i can select a rating from a few radios, then have the div disappear and update the span.

What I'm getting hung up on, perhaps just conceptually, is passing the data around. I want it to say "please rate for *_*_" and have it display the name in the popup box, and have the resulting data get passed back. How do I get the data to display in the div? I know I could do something like this to grab the buttons parent element content

```
$text = $el.parent().find("span").text();
```

but am not sure... how to take it from there. how to display the new div with the contents inside, then pass back the value on div close.

I know this is probably pretty trivial... just not sure how to go about or where to look (or even of any sites that do something similar to take apart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple version that you can look at.  Play with the fiddle to learn how it works.  fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brentmn/k2Yaz/4/

Once you get the basics of it down, ask more questions if you need help improving it.

```
var $owner = undefined;
var $ratingPop = $('#select-rating');
$('#ratings span').on('click', function() {
    $owner = $(this);
    $('input[value="' + $owner.text() + '"]').attr('checked', true);
    $ratingPop.show();
});

$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function() {
    $owner.text($(this).val());
    $ratingPop.hide();
});
```

Comment: Exactly the kinda thing I was looking for, and jsfiddle looks like a big timesaver. 2 for one! thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It's very broad question. You should get familiar with basics. You can find excelent examples of popups in jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#animated

And the logic can be like this:
user clicks on the rating button => you show him a jQuery dialog with rating radio buttons => user clicks on the radio button with particular rate => you closes the dialog while retieving radio's value (e.g. 3) and put this value via one of jQuery methods into your initial display div.